# How to virtualize a windows device (/dev/sda2)

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows, virtualization, devices

i'm using a dualboot windows/ubuntu 16.04, is there a way while i'm on the linux OS, to mount the windows (/dev/sda2) device and then use some kind of virtualization app to run it from my linux?
Perhaps another way to run my already installed windows on my linux?

Thanks.

Comment: You can, [something like that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37779/how-do-i-boot-from-a-liveusb-using-qemu-kvm) *(don't have time to collect all command line options, test, and write an answer; I'd leave it to someone else)*. Note though, this way Windows would see upon boot a completely different set of hardware, i.e. motherboard, GPU — because everything is virtualized. It definitely would be okay for GNU/Linux — but not necessarily for Windows, it might very well go BSOD, or something… Anyway, you'll need to experiment.

Comment: This is possible. What virtualization software do you use? For VirtualBox please check https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk. A technical detail:  You do _not_ mount the Windows partition in this setup. As @Hi-Angel noted, there will be problems with drivers (but they should be installed automatically in modern Windows) but also with activation of Windows since it depends on the particular hardware which cannot be accessed directly when virtualized. However, the virtualization SW can be instructed to mimic the HW.

Comment: Long ago (like a decade) you could use hardware profiles to somewhat limit the churn of ever detecting new Hardware when windows boots in the different environments (having one for real HW and one for the virtual HW). Not sure how much that still applies, but it is still in the KB https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb740879.aspx and might be worth a read.